# Commutator of covariant derivatives to get the curvature/field strength

Tags: gauge-theory, curvature, differentiation, yang-mills, covariance

For notation and convention, please see [Gauge theory formalism](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/519792/) and [Generalizing the covariant derivate for gauge theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/520414/).

The covariant derivative can be used to construct curvatures (called field strengths in the Yang-Mills case).

These are defined as

$$[D_\mu,D_\nu]=-\delta(R_{\mu\nu})$$

where

$$R_{\mu\nu}{}^A= 2 \partial_{[\mu}B_{\nu]}{}^A + B_\nu{}^C B_\mu{}^B f_{BC}{}^A$$

The authors state that this can be derived by using the result from before

"Replace $\epsilon_1$ with $B_\mu$ and replace $\epsilon_2$ with $\epsilon$''

\begin{eqnarray*}
[\delta(\epsilon_1),\delta(\epsilon_2)] &=& \delta(\epsilon_1{}^A \epsilon_2{}^B f_{AB}{}^C) \\
\delta(B_\mu)\delta(\epsilon) - \delta(\epsilon)\delta(B_\mu)&=& \delta(B_\mu{}^A \epsilon^B f_{AB}{}^C) \\
\end{eqnarray*}

**Question: Explicitly, the authors say that by instead now replacing $\epsilon_1$ with $B_\mu$, and $\epsilon_2$ with $B_\nu$, and using the result of the convariance of $D_\mu$, this expression for the curvature can be derived. I am struggling with this. So far I have,**

\begin{eqnarray*}
[\delta(\epsilon_1),\delta(\epsilon_2)] &=& \delta(\epsilon_1{}^A \epsilon_2{}^B f_{AB}{}^C) \\
\delta(B_\mu)\delta(B_\nu) - \delta(B_\nu)\delta(B_\mu)&=& \delta(B_\mu{}^A B_\nu{}^B f_{AB}{}^C) \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Then just writing out the commutator of the covariant derivatives explicitly I have,

\begin{eqnarray*}
[D_\mu,D_\nu] &=& (\partial_\mu - \delta(B_\mu))(\partial_\nu -\delta(B_\nu)) \\
&=& \partial_\mu\partial_\nu - \partial_\mu\delta(B_\nu) - \delta(B_\mu)\partial_\nu +\delta(B_\mu)\delta(B_\nu) -\partial_\nu\partial_\mu + \partial_\nu\delta(B_\mu) + \delta(B_\nu)\partial_\mu - \delta(B_\nu)\delta(B_\mu) \\
&=& \partial_\mu\partial_\nu - \partial_\mu\delta(B_\nu) - \delta(B_\mu)\partial_\nu -\partial_\nu\partial_\mu + \partial_\nu\delta(B_\mu) + \delta(B_\nu)\partial_\mu + \delta(B_\mu{}^A B_\nu{}^B f_{AB}{}^C)
\end{eqnarray*}

**Thoughts on how to proceed:**

1) use the rule from middle/high school with mixed partial second derivatives, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial y} f = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f.$

2) use the suggested form from the definition of $R_{\mu\nu}$ given by the authors.

\begin{eqnarray*}
\delta(2 \partial_{[\mu}B_{\nu]}) &=& \delta(2 \frac{1}{2!}(\partial_\mu B_\nu - \partial_\nu B_\mu)) \\
&=& \delta(\partial_\mu B_\nu) - \delta(\partial_\nu B_\mu) \\
&=& \delta(\partial_\mu) B_\nu + \partial_\mu \delta(B_\nu) - \delta(\partial_\nu) B_\mu - \partial_\nu \delta(B_\mu)
\end{eqnarray*}

**Not sure not to rearrange these terms to work towards the derivation.**

Comment: Which authors? Which reference? Which page?

Comment: Only the one! Freedman and Van Proeyen's Supergravity textbook linked in the other posts (which TeX up the notation too :) )

Answer (score 2):

What book are you using? The notation is horribly obscure. Here is the standard and straightforward calculation:
$$
\nabla_\mu = \partial_\mu+A_\mu.
$$
where $A_\mu$ takes values in the Lie algebra of the gauge group. In other words
$$
A_\mu= A_\mu^a \lambda_a 
$$
where 
$$
[\lambda_a,\lambda_b]= {f_{ab}}^c \lambda_c
$$
and the $A_\mu^a$ are just number-valued functions of position.
Now expanding out and using $\partial_{\mu\nu}= \partial_{\nu\mu}$ we have
$$
[\partial_\mu +A_\mu,\partial_\nu+ A_\nu]= \partial_\mu A_\nu -\partial_\nu A_\mu +[A_\mu,A_\nu]\\
= \lambda_c(\partial_\mu A^c_\nu -\partial_\nu A^c_\mu +  {f_{ab}}^c A^a_\mu A^b_\nu)
$$